# Amazon product api categorization fails

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, e-commerce

I am using the Amazon PHP API (MarketplaceWebService) to create Products from my personal shop in the Amazon sellercentral.

I am submitting productinformation, prices and images in seperate feeds (_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_, _POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_ and _POST_PRODUCT_IMAGE_DATA_).

For some reason the Categorization of the product always fails

The relevant section in my xml would be:

```
    <DescriptionData>
      <Title>'.$product["Title"].'</Title>
      <Brand>'.$product["Brand"].'</Brand>
      <Description>'.$product["Description"].'</Description>
      <MSRP currency="GBP">'.$product["MSRP"].'</MSRP>
      <Manufacturer>'.$product["Manufacturer"].'</Manufacturer>
      <ItemType>toys-and-games</ItemType>
    </DescriptionData>
    <ProductData>
    <ToysBaby>
    <ProductType>ToysAndGames</ProductType>
    </ToysBaby>
    </ProductData>
```

Am I missing something here? I can not find further information on the categorization of products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're in the UK, so you will want to use the `<RecommendedBrowseNode></RecommendedBrowseNode>` tag to categorize your products. You can find more information and an example on pages 40-41 of the Selling on Amazon Guide to XML:
https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V351673846_.pdf